# Typeerror: 'tuple' object is not callable in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

When I run this code:

```
SURFACER = SURFACEFONT.get_rect()
SURFACER.center(400, (ipnum*100))
```

I get this error:

```
File "index.py", line 62, in <module>
    myFunction()
  File "index.py", line 55, in drawGamesToScreen
    SURFACER.center(400, ipnum*100)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: I guess you want to run `.center()` on something else than the rectangle tuple. Maybe on `SURFACEFONT`?

Comment: Looks like it's rather than center is a tuple attribute and not a function.

Comment: +Klaus D. No, that didn't work. It returned the error:

AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'center'

Answer (score 2):

`center` on a `Rect` instance returns a tuple, so you can't use `.center(x,y)` here. Just asign a new tuple, like this:

```
SURFACER.center = (400, (ipnum*100))
```